# sql syntax error when trying to send nodejs to mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am getting this error and have been stuck on it and i just cannot find an sql error!
i am getting this error

> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'x Disney – Lautsprecher für die Dusche mit Micky Maus-Design, asos, Typo, nul' at line 1

which corresponds to line main.json.result[1] + ", " +

module.exports = {
    products_into_db: function () {

```
const insert_products = db_config.fetch("INSERT INTO asos_products " +
"(handle, title,vendor,category,type,gender,color,brand,price,beforeSalePrice,currency,product_code) " +
"VALUES (" + 
main.json.result[0] + ", "+
main.json.result[1] + ", " +
main.json.result[2] + ", " +
main.json.result[3] + ", " +
main.json.result[4] + ", " +
main.json.result[5] + ", "+
main.json.result[6] + ", " +
main.json.result[7] + ", " +
main.json.result[8] + ", " +
main.json.result[9] + ", " +
main.json.result[11] + ", " +
main.json.result[12] + ") " 
)
return insert_products
```

this is my sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `asos_products` (
  `internal_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `handle` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `vendor` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float NOT NULL,
  `beforeSalePrice` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`internal_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SELECT * FROM enroute.asos_products;
```

Comment: 12 columns and 13 values?
also use main.json.result.join() rather using + ''+','+''....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround main.json.result[i] with inverted commas for columns who have types of varchar. Example -

```
", '" +
main.json.result[5] + "', "+
```

It should work then

Comment: "VALUES ('" + 
    main.json.result[0] + "', '" +
    main.json.result[1] + "', '"  +
    main.json.result[2] + "', '" +
    main.json.result[3] + "', '" +
    main.json.result[4] + "', '" +
    main.json.result[5] + "', '"+
    main.json.result[6] + "', '"  +
    main.json.result[7] + "', " +
    main.json.result[8] + ", "  +
    main.json.result[9] + ", '"  +
    main.json.result[10] + "',"  +
    main.json.result[11] + ") "

Comment: and this is error i am getting now: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', , '1340376',undefined)' at line 1

Comment: "INSERT INTO asos_products " +
"(handle, title,vendor,category,type,gender,color,brand,price,beforeSalePrice,currency,product_code) " +
"VALUES (" + 
main.json.result[0] + ", "+
main.json.result[1] + ", " +
main.json.result[2] + ", " +
main.json.result[3] + ", " +
main.json.result[4] + ", " +
main.json.result[5] + ", "+
main.json.result[6] + ", " +
main.json.result[7] + ", " +
main.json.result[8] + ", " +
main.json.result[9] + ", " +
main.json.result[11] + ", " +
main.json.result[12] + ") "

^convert this statement into string and post here the value of that string if possible

Comment: btw, it seems like some of the values are not in the variable. Please check the values of main.json.result[12], main.json.result[11] and main.json.result[9]. These variables might not have definite values.